# How to upload image like a form-data with ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, file-upload, ionic-framework

I need help with some part of my application! Im trying to upload avatar image with Http Post Request use CordovaFileTransfer and Cordova Camera. And when im trying to do that i have error on my ionic app code 414 url request too long! I use Wordpress Rest Api Json User Plus plugin!

When i send file with Postman it's working, but when i trying to that with code i have error!

That my Button

```
    <button ng-click="uploadAvatar()"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i> Upload Avatar</button>
```

That my Controller

```js
 $scope.uploadAvatar =  function() {
  var user = AuthService.getUser();
    var options = {
         quality : 75,
         destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
         sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
         allowEdit : true,
         encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
         popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
         targetWidth: 500,
         targetHeight: 500,
         saveToPhotoAlbum: false
     };
     $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options)
     .then(function(imageData) {
        $http.post('http://hannation.me/api/userplus/avatar_upload?cookie=' + user.cookie + '&key=57f211a0354d7' + '&avatar=data:image/png;base64,' + imageData)
        
     }, function(error) {
         console.error(error);
     });
    }
```

What i do wrong? I think my code is correct because code try to send the file to server right? 
Please help me i lose one week with this small part!

Im changing to this with

```js
 $scope.uploadAvatar =  function() {
  var user = AuthService.getUser();
var options = {
     quality : 75,
     destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
     sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
     allowEdit : true,
     encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
     popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
     targetWidth: 500,
     targetHeight: 500,
     saveToPhotoAlbum: false
 };
 $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options)
 .then(function(imageData) {
    var req = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://hannation.me/api/userplus/avatar_upload',
      data: 'cookie=' + user.cookie + '&key=57f211a0354d7' + '&avatar=data:image/png;base64' + imageData
    }
    $http(req).then(function(response){
         console.log(req);
      }, 
      function(error) {
         console.error(error);
      })
})
  }
```

But it steel doesn't work! Right now i have 404 error!

[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ku4Oe.png)

[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqVFl.png)

Comment: you are using `$http.post` but you are passing data in url. for pass data in url you have to use `get`

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya That all error? Let me try

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya same error with get! 414 Request URL Too Long

HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long.

Comment: you have to create post api. make your api to support post request

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya I send with POSTMAN with POST method it work! APi is work, but with my code it doesn't work!

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya I was update my answer with your code! Its give 404 error

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya Add two image in answer from POSTMAN! Check

Comment: why are you passing data in url and post req both? proper way is to either do get or either post. not mix of both

Comment: take a look at this tutorial once https://devdactic.com/ionic-image-upload-php/

Comment: Because in documentation to this API:
U need to send with POST request File-Type) That why

Comment: if you are using `Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL`  you should post encoded image data  `encodeURIComponent(imageData);`

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are mismatch with `post` and `get`, you are writing `$http.post` but you are passing data in url.

```
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://hannation.me/api/userplus/avatar_upload',
    data: cookie=' + user.cookie + '&key=57f211a0354d7' + '&avatar=data:image/png;base64,' + imageData
}

$http(req).then(function(response){
     console.log(response);
}, function(error){
     console.log(error);
});
```

check [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) of angularjs http

Comment: Its back me 404 not found!

Comment: can you upload  POSTMAN screenshot